# Is there anything wrong with ConfigurationManager in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I read many topics related to configuration manager but could not resolve the issue. I just want to read the connection string as well some appsetting keys from a CLASS LIBRARY in the web application.

I have reference to System.Configuration Class.

This is my code:

```
using System.Configuration;

...

string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cbuddydb"].ConnectionString;
string strUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
string strPwd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
```

But it seems reading from a different config file. not from the web.config in my project. Because the value read is wrong.

My `web.config` is below:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
  <system.data>
    <connectionStrings>
      <clear />
      <add name="cbuddydb" connectionstring=
           "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=myDataBase;Persist Security Info=True;
            User=@username;Password=@password;Option=3" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" password=""/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings >
      <clear />
      <add key="username" value ="6/0RUNnSmUBsbdNoCg+9Sw=="/>
      <add key="password" value =""/>
    </appSettings>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Maybe you have some transformations for debug/release?

Comment: Please post your web.config, and your actual and expected results.

Comment: In the .NET configuration system, **by design**, the `ConfigurationManager` always reads from the **hosting application's** config file - **not** from the class library's own separate file. If you need to have config settings for your class library - you have to put them into the `app.config` or `web.config` of the application that's using your class library

Comment: Why are you referencing conn strings/ app settings by *index* rather than by *name*?

Comment: @RB web.config is added.

Comment: @marc_s : i am also trying to read from web.config file only.

Comment: @Jamiec : changed from Index to name. now the error is "Object reference not set"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is because of configuration file inheritance. The connection string at index 0 may not be in your config file, but it may have been inherited from machine.config etc. Have a look at ASP.Net config file hierarchy and inheritance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx

You could clear the inherited connection strings by specifying the following in your web.config

```
 <connectionStrings> 
     <clear />  
     <add name=”MyConnString” connectionString=“Whatever“  /> 
  </connectionStrings>
```

**EDIT: In your config, place your connectionStrings and appSettings tags directly below the configuration element. They should not be within the system.data element. They are direct children of the configuration element. And remove the extra password attribute after the providerName. I can't validate your connection string, since I don't know how you're using it.**

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="cbuddydb"  connectionString=
       "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=myDataBase;Persist Security Info=True;
        User=@username;Password=@password;Option=3" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings >        
    <add key="username" value ="6/0RUNnSmUBsbdNoCg+9Sw=="/>
    <add key="password" value =""/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.data>
....
```

You should consider encrypting sensitive information in your config file, like passwords.

Comment: Thanks @Reubz i added <clear/>. also i changed from index to name but the error is "Object reference not set".

Comment: the ConfigurationManager is called in a class library in the solution not in the aspx project. is that a problem? Also i noticed a web.Debug.config and web.release.config files located near web.config. not sure when is it used.

Comment: thank u very much.. that was exactly problem. also i was using lowercase 's' in connectionString=